# How do you force Breeze metadata generated properties to be camelCase?

Tags: breeze

I would like to change the serializer for Breeze so that my javascript objects are camelCased. In the documentation it says this can be done but says it is TO BE EXPLAINED.

> You can change the formatter's configuration [TO BE EXPLAINED] but if
>   you do so you, you are responsible for ensuring that your changes do
>   not conflict with Breeze expectation.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: It remains to be explained but you would not ... and should not change the formatter's configuration for this particular purpose ... or in any way that conflicts with the Breeze client expectations. See the answer below for the alternative you seek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest is to simply call

```
breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
```

before your first query ( or before you create your first metaData store).

There is more information [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata#NamingConvention), [here](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/NamingConvention.html) and [here](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html)

The built in **NamingConvention.camelCase** is a pretty simplistic implementation of camel casing so you can also write your own naming conventions like this:

```
var namingConv = new breeze.NamingConvention({
    serverPropertyNameToClient: function (serverPropertyName, prop) {
        if (prop && prop.isDataProperty && prop.dataType === DataType.Boolean) {
            return "is" + serverPropertyName;
        } else {
            return serverPropertyName.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase() + serverPropertyName.substr(1);
        }
    },
    clientPropertyNameToServer: function (clientPropertyName, prop) {
        if (prop && prop.isDataProperty && prop.dataType === DataType.Boolean) {
            return clientPropertyName.substr(2);
        } else {
            return clientPropertyName.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + clientPropertyName.substr(1);
        }
    }            
});
namingConv.setAsDefault();
```

Comment: I use this setting. Though I personally prefer that this was the default setting out of the box, I'm fine with setting it.

Comment: I use it too. :) ... But for the breeze product the rationale was to meet the 'principle of least surprise' so, by default, property names on the server match those on the client.

Comment: Read all about it in the ["NamingConvention" section](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata#NamingConvention) of the documentation.